# Facebook api warning message during compilation

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

I integrated facebook api in project. I am getting this warning message in its code. Here is the code details.

```
    FBXMLHandler* handler = [[[FBXMLHandler alloc] init] autorelease];
  NSXMLParser* parser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];

  parser.delegate = handler ; // Warning message is occurring here
```

// waning message= class FBXMLHandler does not implement the NSXMLParserDelegate protocol //
      [parser parse];

How will I remove this warning message "class FBXMLHandler does not implement the NSXMLParserDelegate protocol" from the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk/issues/35) you may be using the wrong Facebook SDK.

The official & supported one is [located here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk).

The subtle difference is the old, deprecated one is called `facebook-iphone-sdk` whilst the new, officially supported one is called `facebook-ios-sdk`

Answer (score 1):

FBXMLHandler class should implement NSXMLParserDelegate methods - like didStartElement etc. 
and check header file (.h file) of FBXMLHandler for protocol decleration for NSXMLParserDelegate protocol.

Comment: ignore warning if App deployment target is less than 4.0

Comment: I am using iOS4.0. is there any option to ignore warning on this tool? I am new in iOS.

Comment: Whilst Pawan's answer is useful for why you are seeing this error message in an Objective-C context, I don't believe it to be useful in this specific, Facebook related context. Please see my answer.

Comment: Please see micpringle answer.